# oninvalid attribute not rendering in React js

Tags: html, reactjs, validation

I am trying to add `oninvalid` attribute in HTML element under React js code. (using react hooks not class based)

```js
 const openEndedAnswer = answer => {
        return (<>
            <input type="text" className="form-control"
                required="required"
                oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')"
                oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"
                maxLength="255"
                id={`answer_${question.id}`}
                name={`answer_${question.id}`}
                onChange={e => updatePostForm(e)}
                pattern=".*[^ ].*"
                title=" No white spaces"
            />
        </>)
    }
```

But it never renders in the browser. all other attributes can be seen in F12 source view.

Comment: It should be `oninvalid={this.setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')}`

Comment: @SuthanBala already tried that. it gives error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setCustomValidity')`

Comment: Try this `oninvalid={() => this.setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The attribute names should `onInvalid` instead of `oninvalid` and `onInput` instead of `oninput`. Additionally, you need to call the `setCustomValidity` function on the input field as follow (because the input field is the target of the event):

```
onInvalid={e => e.target.setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')}
onInput={e => e.target.setCustomValidity('')}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using React with javascript this should work:

```
onInvalid={e => e.target.setCustomValidity('Your custom message')}
onInput={e => e.target.setCustomValidity('')}
```

But if you are working with React with typescript you also need to add this:

```
onInvalid={e => (e.target as HTMLInputElement).setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')}
onInput={e => (e.target as HTMLInputElement).setCustomValidity('')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try onInvalid instead:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <form>
      Name:{" "}
      <input
        type="text"
        onInvalid={() => console.log("working!")}
        name="fname"
        required
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```